# How can I set the `OnFocus` property for a TextBox when creating them dynamically (on button click) at runtime in c#/XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently creating new textboxes from a derived class (`MyTextBox : TextBox`) when the user presses a button at runtime.

How do I set the `OnFocus` property for the newly created MyTextBox instances if I am creating them this way? Usually I would create them on the XAML designer form and do it there, but not possible with this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created your `MyTextBox`, just add the following line:

```
myTextBox.GotFocus += OnGotFocusHandler;
```

If you just tab after typing the `+=` Visual Studio will create the method stub for you.

You then fill out the handler as you would when it's created from the XAML.

You should remove the handler if the operation is a one time thing. If you want to do the same thing every time the text box gets focus then leave it in place. You should also remove the handler just before the text box falls out of scope, otherwise the textbox won't get disposed of until the application closes.

Comment: One more question for my own learning - at the end of whatever i do when i have gotfocus - should i remove the handler using the -= operator? and if so, is this purely for memory reasons or something else. I only ask as i have seen this elsewhere and am curious

Comment: @Ricardinho - You should remove the handler if the operation is a one time thing. If you want to do the same thing every time the text box gets focus then leave it in place. You should also remove the handler just before the text box falls out of scope.

Comment: Actually - if i may...is it possible to create a single event handler for all instances of a particular type?  So for example, if i am created 10 new MyTextBoxes, can i have one OnFocus event handler which will work for all 10?

Comment: @Ricardinho - yes you can reuse the same handler for all your instances. Just point to the same handler method for each.